# Move Add To Cart button and Variation Selector above product short description in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

How can I move Add To Cart button and Variation Selector above product short description (between price and short description) in Woocommerce product page?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the following code snippet:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'customizing_variable_products', 1 );
function customizing_variable_products() {
    global $product;
    if( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) return;

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 15 );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).*

Tested and works.

> If you want that for all product types, you should remove (from the code):
>
> ```
> global $product;
> if( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) return;
> ```

[image]

Comment: For some reason this code adds another Add To Cart button and variation selector above the original one instead of moving the original one above the short description. Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: @Ged The issue could be that your theme (or a plugin) is already manipulating hook and their priorities. I have tested tis code on Storefront theme and it just works perfectly… I have changed the priority of the first `add_action()` to `1` *(not sure that it will change something for you)*… and added a screen shot.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue still persists. Do you have any possible suggestions on what can be done with the theme to to see if it is actually manipulating the hooks?